# Ef core not ignoring columns in generated SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using EF for .NET Core

I have a table which I dont want to bring back all the columns for in a query

```
(from ae in Table1.Select(x => new {x.CreatedDate, x.EntryId, x.Amount})
  join si in Table2.Select(x => new {x.SessionId, x.IdToFind})
.Where(y => y.SessionId == Guid.Parse("52F0C862-15D0-4C7A-975D-285C618342B0")) on ae.EntryId equals si.IdToFind
 select new
 {
   create output
 }).ToList();
```

As you can see, I am specifically only including 2 columns from Table2

```
SELECT [a].[EntryId], [a].[Amount]
FROM [Table1] AS [a]
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[CreatedBy], [s].[CreatedDate], [s].[IdToFind], [s].[SessionId], [s].[UpdatedDate], [s].[UpdateddBy]
    FROM [Table2] AS [s]
    WHERE [s].[SessionId] = '52f0c862-15d0-4c7a-975d-285c618342b0'
) AS [t] ON [a].[EntryId] = [t].[IdToFind]
```

When I use LinqPad to evaluate the generated SQL, I can see that all the columns from Table 2 have been include

How can I prevent this?  I dont want to use the Ignore option on the model loading because in other situations I may want the other columns

Comment: You should just join the tables or better yet if you're joining on a FK relationship use the Navigation property instead.  What you have in the final select should be what the generated SQL will return.  However the problem is that some versions of EF Core will do part of the query in memory and I'm guessing doing the sub selects might be the culprit.

Comment: @juharr not sure what you mean by just join the tables, that’s what I am doing? I can’t put a foreign key in because table 2 is a helper table that stores IDs which could be those in several tables

Comment: I mean just do `from ae in Table1 join si in Table2 on ae.EntryId equals si.IdToFind where y.SessionId == id select new {...}`, And try assigning the parsed Guid to a variable and use that in the query instead of the `Guid.Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this syntax:

```
ResultClass result =(from ae in Table1
  join si in Table2
 on ae.EntryId equals si.IdToFind
where(si.SessionId == Guid.Parse("52F0C862-15D0-4C7A-975D-285C618342B0"))
 select new ResultClass
 {
   ae.CreatedDate, 
ae.EntryId, 
ae.Amount,
si.SessionId, 
si.IdToFind
 }).ToList();
```

But in this case you will need to create a new class that contains properties of both classes or you get an anonymos object that you have to use immediately.

When I like to avoid creating a new class  I usually add some [NotMapped] properties to one of Table1 or Table2 classes in a partial class code and use this class instead of the ResultClass

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work, however mixing the Linq query syntax and Fluent methods isn't making it very readable at all and I suspect that may be responsible for the unexpected query generation. Particularly this:

```
(from ae in Table1.Select(x => new {x.CreatedDate, x.EntryId, x.Amount})
  join si in Table2.Select(x => new {x.SessionId, x.IdToFind}).Where(y => y.SessionId == Guid.Parse("52F0C862-15D0-4C7A-975D-285C618342B0"))
```

Which has the `Where` condition on the Table2 Select.

From what I can deduce from your approach, you are being too eager with your optimization:

With EF queries, `Select` projections do not need to be done at a per-entity level, they are done at the end of the expression and EF will work out exactly what columns from what table need to be included. That said, you *can* pre-select columns and EF should work it all out, but it will do so from your final projection.

Provided you have an actual FK between Table1.EntryId and Table2.IdToFind, ideally you would want that relationship mapped out in the entities rather than relying on an explicit join. Navigation properties make it much easier to organize queries, but there can be more generic cases where Table2 can serve multiple other tables etc.

Assuming that you want to just build an output from the CreatedDate, EntryId, Amount, and SessionId from these two loosely related tables:

```
var results = context.Table1
    .Join(context.Table2.Where(t2 => t2.SessionId == sessionId), 
        t1 => t1.EntryId, 
        t2 => t2.IdToFind, 
        (t1, t2) => new { Table1 = t1, Table2 = t2 })
    .Select(x => new ResultViewModel
    {
        EntryId = x.Table1.EntryId,
        CreatedDate = x.Table1.CreatedDate,
        Amount = x.Table1.Amount,
        // ...
    }).ToList();
```

Assuming you don't even need anything from Table2 then:

```
    // ...
    .Join(context.Table2.Where(t2 => t2.SessionId == sessionId), 
        t1 => t1.EntryId, 
        t2 => t2.IdToFind, 
        (t1, t2) => t1)
    .Select(x => new ResultViewModel
    {
        EntryId = x.EntryId,
        CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate,
        Amount = x.Amount
    }).ToList();
```

When you read the Linq it may seem like EF would be selecting all columns from the related tables so you'd want to add `Select` projections there, but they are not needed. The final query should select columns strictly by the final `Select` projection.  I would avoid mixing Linq query language (`from Table1 join Table2 select ....`) with the Fluent builder methods. IMO the Fluent methods are easier to read from a C# code perspective, but ultimately I'd use one or the other, not both.

Comment: ok thanks.  I have just tried both (I actually need the second one without the reference to CreatedDate.  In both cases CreatedDate is in the generated SQL even though I dont use it?

Comment: CreatedDate shouldn't appear if it isn't used in any condition (i.e. `Where`, `Join`, etc) or in the Projection. (`Select`). If you put up the actual Linq expression you are using there may be an explanation in there for where a column might be included when not expected.